# Fazer um create se FindOneUpdate não achar nada

Tags: node.js

Ola, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em node.js e estou com dificuldade.

Caso o meu findOneUpdate não encontrar nada eu queria que fosse realizado um create, porém não achei um jeito de criar um if ou algo assim.

segue o código:

exports.getAndUpdateByNome = async (data) => {
        await staticAnalise
            .findOneAndUpdate(data.nome, {
                $set: {
                    nome: data.nome,
                    data: data.data
                }
            });
}

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOpt. Com tão pouca informação é impossível de sugerir qualquer coisa. Tente ser mais claro em sua questão e adicione mais informações, como o banco de dados que é usado.

Answer (score 0):

Está faltando informação nessa pergunta, ao que se refere esse `findOneAndUpdate`?

Pelo código dá para deduzir que é um método do MongoDB, mas as tags nem a pergunta dizem nada a respeito.

De toda forma, o método `findOneAndUpdate` recebe três parâmetros: os filtros para encontrar o documento que será modificado, os updates, e opções. Uma dessas opções é o `upsert`, que quando ativado, cria um novo documento utilizando esses updates caso nenhum documento tenha sido encontrado com os seus filtros.

Exemplo:

```
staticAnalise.findOneAndUpdate(
    { nome: data.nome }, 
    { $set: {
        nome: data.nome,
        data: data.data
    } },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, tentei aqui e gravou por cima do dado já presente, alterando totalmente a informação.

Comment: mas não criou um novo documento.

Comment: @TFGROOVE, mas não foi isso que você pediu? Se encontrar um documento, faz update, se não encontrar, cria um novo. Ou o objetivo era retornar um erro se já existisse um documento com o mesmo nome do banco de dados?

Comment: Então ele não criou um novo ele alterou meu dado presente ali